# How to proof differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: $f(x):$ function , for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
show that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 3|x-y|^{\frac{3}{2}}~\Rightarrow~f'(x)=0 $$

Comment: You're missing some quantifiers: presumably, you mean to say ***for all*** $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: mean for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$ -h^{\frac 3 2} \leq f(x+h) - f(x) \leq h^{\frac 3 2}.  $$

Answer (score 5):

Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then we have
$$0\leq|f'(x)|=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq\lim_{y\to x}3\sqrt{|x-y|}=0\Rightarrow |f'(x)|=0\Rightarrow f'(x)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Remember the definition $$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}.$$ What can you deduce about $\lvert f'(x)\lvert$?